# STM32 UART: combining interrupt and DMA modes

Tags: stm32, uart, interrupts, dma

I am trying to use `UART3` of `STM32F103K8` to rx data in interrupt mode and tx in DMA mode.
Reception works well, but transmission has a bug: first portion of data is transmitted just fine and ISR is called.
After that, `huart.gState == HAL_UART_STATE_READY` is never achieved and any subsequent transmission fails.

So, the questions are:

1. Is it OK to use interrupt mode rx and DMA mode tx for single UART? Are there any examples?
2. Given that all DMA channels have same preemption priority and are used havily and simultaniously, can it potentially result in data loss, IRQ conflicts or have other negative consequenses?

Comment: yes, i just think of tx nd x as independent to be honest but I do not use HAL. I roll my own. I do not trust HAL because you never really know what it is doing

Comment: Thanks. Yes, HAL is buggy and has a big overhead, but the project is based on that library. Still trying to figure out the cause, UART1 in same project has almost identical code but uses DMA for both rx and tx.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the project was refactored to use STM LL Drivers, and with [this](https://github.com/MaJerle/STM32_USART_DMA) approach, allowing to receive variable-length packets with DMA, the problem was solved. Real cause of the problem is still unknown, most likely its a bug in the project code or possible in STM HAL library.